# How to delete text form txt file using python

Tags: python

Suppose a txt file consist of :

```
1 2 22
4 5 66
```

how can I delete first line of it . i.e `1 2 22`

Comment: Do you always want to delete the first line? Or you wan to delete the line containing `1 2 22`? What have you tried until now?

Comment: read all text into memory, delete line, write all new text to file

Comment: always the first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
input_file = open('filename.txt')
output_file = open('output_filename.txt', 'w')
for line in input_file.readlines()[1:]:
    output_file.write(line + '\n')
output_file.close()
```

Same thing using single file:

```
input_file = open('filename.txt')
input_data = [line for line in input_file.readlines()]
input_file.close()

output_file = open('filename.txt', 'w')
for line in input_data[1:]:
    output_file.write(line + '\n')
output_file.close()
```

Comment: It does not writes the file content to 'output_filename.txt' , Why do we require 2 files here I have tried examples using 2 files , Is there a way too do it with single file ??

Comment: Sorry It works fine but is there a way to solve it using single file ?